# Collision Detection for Character Crouching Not Working in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I was following a tutorial but I'm having trouble with the `CheckCollisionOverlap()` function. It's meant to check for a collision over the player's head when the player is crouching, but for some reason he won't stand back up (or stop walking in place).

If I comment out `PhysicsUpdate()` and `CheckCollisionOverlap()`, he will crouch, walk crouch, and stand up from crouch, so I know the problem has to exist within that logic.

In the tutorial comments section, someone mentioned that they changed the value of the layermask. I named a layermask `Player` and assigned it to layer 8 but that still didn't do anything.

Tutorial Link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVxvwRAYeHU

```cs
    using UnityEngine;
 
    public class CrouchingState : State
    {
       float playerSpeed;
       bool belowCeiling;
       bool crouchHeld;
 
       bool grounded;
       float gravityValue;
       Vector3 currentVelocity;
 
 
       public CrouchingState(Character _character, StateMachine _stateMachine):base(_character, _stateMachine)
       {
           character = _character;
           stateMachine = _stateMachine;
       }
 
       public override void Enter()
       {
           base.Enter();
 
           character.animator.SetTrigger("crouch");  
           belowCeiling = false;
           crouchHeld = false;
           gravityVelocity.y = 0;
 
           playerSpeed = character.crouchSpeed;
           character.controller.height = character.crouchColliderHeight;
           character.controller.center = new Vector3(0f, character.crouchColliderHeight / 2f, 0f);
           grounded = character.controller.isGrounded;
           gravityValue = character.gravityValue;
 
        
       }
 
       public override void Exit()
       {
           base.Exit();
           character.controller.height = character.normalColliderHeight;
           character.controller.center = new Vector3(0f, character.normalColliderHeight / 2f, 0f);
           gravityVelocity.y = 0f;
           character.playerVelocity = new Vector3(input.x, 0, input.y);
           character.animator.SetTrigger("move");
       }
 
       public override void HandleInput()
       {
           base.HandleInput();
           if (crouchAction.triggered && !belowCeiling)
           {
               crouchHeld = true;
           }
           input = moveAction.ReadValue<Vector2>();
           velocity = new Vector3(input.x, 0, input.y);
 
           velocity = velocity.x * character.cameraTransform.right.normalized + velocity.z * character.cameraTransform.forward.normalized;
           velocity.y = 0f;
       }
 
       public override void LogicUpdate()
       {
           base.LogicUpdate();
           character.animator.SetFloat("speed", input.magnitude, character.speedDampTime, Time.deltaTime);
 
           if (crouchHeld)
           {
               stateMachine.ChangeState(character.standing);
           }
       }
 
       public override void PhysicsUpdate()
       {
           base.PhysicsUpdate();
           belowCeiling = CheckCollisionOverlap(character.transform.position + Vector3.up *    character.normalColliderHeight);
           gravityVelocity.y += gravityValue * Time.deltaTime;
           grounded = character.controller.isGrounded;
           if (grounded && gravityVelocity.y < 0)
           {
               gravityVelocity.y = 0f;
           }
           currentVelocity = Vector3.Lerp(currentVelocity, velocity, character.velocityDampTime);
 
           character.controller.Move(currentVelocity * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed + gravityVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
 
           if (velocity.magnitude > 0)
           {
               character.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(character.transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(velocity), character.rotationDampTime);
           }
       }
 
       public bool CheckCollisionOverlap(Vector3 targetPositon)
       {
           int layerMask = 1 << 8;
           layerMask = ~layerMask;
           RaycastHit hit;
 
           Vector3 direction = targetPositon - character.transform.position;
           if (Physics.Raycast(character.transform.position, direction, out hit, character.normalColliderHeight, layerMask))
           {
               Debug.DrawRay(character.transform.position, direction * hit.distance, Color.yellow);
               return true;
           }
           else
           {
               Debug.DrawRay(character.transform.position, direction * character.normalColliderHeight, Color.white);
               return false;
           }       
       }
 
 
   }
```

Comment: I hope you aren't using DI in Unity.  Also, I don't see the need to encapsulate `MonoBehaviour`s by defining your own `PhysicsUpdate`, `HandleInput` and `LogicUpdate` unless of course you are creating external pre-compiled assembly plug-ins for Unity and doing most of development external to Unity much like the team for Homeworld: Deserts of Kharak did.

Comment: I didn't write it, someone else did. I'm following this tutorial I found off youtube.

Comment: I checked the layer mask as I though that might be the problem but after looking at the error log with this  Debug.Log(Convert.ToString(layerMask)); , it doesn't seem to be a problem. I honestly don't know what's wrong as all I did was copy this script from the authors site.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change all the layers of the children in the player gameobject as well. Not really sure why that worked, but its responding.